# How do I define and assign Subnet and IP addresses to Containers using Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I think what I am trying to do is straight forward, but reading through the docker compose documentation section on Networking https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ I find no useful information :(

I want to create 2 subnets (this could be more in the future - but for now, let's have it at two) and be able to manually assign IP addresses from each subnet to the container I specify in docker-compose.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  You usually can't directly access the container-private IP addresses from outside Docker space, and inside Docker space the Compose-managed networks also provide DNS that can resolve a container name; there's rarely a need to manage these IP addresses directly.  (Even using multiple networks in a single `docker-compose.yml` file doesn't seem to have a lot of benefit.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this compose file, you can add as many n/w's you want:-

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      mgmnt:
        ipv4_address: "192.168.80.5"
  tomcat:
    container_name: tomcat
    image: tomcat:latest
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "8009:8009"
    networks:
      mgmnt:
        ipv4_address: "192.168.80.6"
      local:
        ipv4_address: "10.10.0.10"  
    depends_on:
     - mysql

networks:
  mgmnt:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 192.168.0.0/16
         gateway: 192.168.0.1
  local:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.10.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.10.0.1
```

Comment: what if I want `tomcat` to be part of two subnets? How will that look like?